# Cannot send non-SOAP rate request to FedEx

Tags: integration, fedex

Trying to send non-SOAP rate request to FedEx.  The following XML works with SOAP Env and Body when I send their SOAP endpoint.  It says in the documentation that they offer an XML-only solution, and that is formatted exactly the same as the SOAP request.  Sending to https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/xml.  Please let me know if anyone has any insight.

```
<RateRequest>
  <WebAuthenticationDetail>
    <UserCredential>
      <Key>omitted</Key>
      <Password>omitted</Password>
    </UserCredential>
  </WebAuthenticationDetail>
  <ClientDetail>
    <AccountNumber>omitted</AccountNumber>
    <MeterNumber>omitted</MeterNumber>
  </ClientDetail>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>
    <Major>28</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <RequestedShipment>
    <ServiceType>FEDEX_2_DAY</ServiceType>
    <Shipper>
      <Address>
        <StreetLines>4500 WEST 46TH STREET</StreetLines>
        <City>CHICAGO</City>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>IL</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>60632</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </Shipper>
    <Recipient>
      <Address>
        <City>TAMPA</City>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>FL</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>33616</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </Recipient>
    <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
    <RequestedPackageLineItems>
      <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
      <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
      <Weight>
        <Units>LB</Units>
        <Value>10</Value>
      </Weight>
    </RequestedPackageLineItems>
  </RequestedShipment>
</RateRequest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there. The root element of your xml document is missing the namespace http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v28.

In a SOAP message the namespace would be defined on the *Envelope* element. Because the data sent via the plain XML interface does not contain the wrapping Envelope and Body tags that are specific to SOAP, you have to add the namespace to the *RateRequest* element.

Your request should then be:

```
<RateRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v28">
  <WebAuthenticationDetail>
    <UserCredential>
      <Key>omitted</Key>
      <Password>omitted</Password>
    </UserCredential>
  </WebAuthenticationDetail>
  <ClientDetail>
    <AccountNumber>omitted</AccountNumber>
    <MeterNumber>omitted</MeterNumber>
  </ClientDetail>
  <Version>
    <ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>
    <Major>28</Major>
    <Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
  </Version>
  <RequestedShipment>
    <ServiceType>FEDEX_2_DAY</ServiceType>
    <Shipper>
      <Address>
        <StreetLines>4500 WEST 46TH STREET</StreetLines>
        <City>CHICAGO</City>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>IL</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>60632</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </Shipper>
    <Recipient>
      <Address>
        <City>TAMPA</City>
        <StateOrProvinceCode>FL</StateOrProvinceCode>
        <PostalCode>33616</PostalCode>
        <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </Recipient>
    <PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
    <RequestedPackageLineItems>
      <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
      <GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
      <Weight>
        <Units>LB</Units>
        <Value>10</Value>
      </Weight>
    </RequestedPackageLineItems>
  </RequestedShipment>
</RateRequest>
```

Also, don't forget to set the following headers in your request:

```
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, text/plain, text/html, */*
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Comment: Hello Diego!  Thank you very much!  I will go ahead and try this once I am done with the 5 million other things on my plate lol.  I was on vacation so it took me a bit to reply.  I will let you know the verdict when I know.  I hope you had a wonderful holiday.

Comment: Diego Colantoni - Sent this exact request to https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/xml, and I am getting this error message: validation failure for RateRequest Error:cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'RateRequest'.  I set the headers to what is shown in the documentation.  If you have any other suggestions please let me know.  Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Hey @KennethDale1! Sounds like 2021 is keeping you busy already. I've just tried to send the exact same request, and I did get a successful response. I.e. `curl --header "Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, text/plain, text/html, */*" --header "Content-Type: text/xml" --data @request.txt "https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/xml"` where request.txt contains the request body. I know that FedEx were updating the testing environment last couple of weeks (see [FedEx announcements](https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/announcements.html)), maybe try again now?

Comment: Hello Diego!  It worked!  I have not been on the branch with my work, so I have been trying through Postman.  Didn't get it to go through there, but added the Namespace to my C# root element and that seemed to do the trick.  I could have sworn I tried this before...  Maybe it did have to do with the test environment update.  In any event, thank you for all of your help!  Hopefully someone else will benefit from this post!

Comment: Hi Kenneth, great news! I've been following the [FedEx docs](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/webhelp/ws/2020/WebServicesLandingPage.html), but find them sometimes overwhelming. Glad it worked at the end!